# How do you delay and schedule a stage to only run the latest build in an Azure Devops yaml pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

How do you schedule a stage to run at a particular time of day in a multi stage azure devops pipeline but for only the latest build?

For example, let's say I have a combined build and release pipeline...

- I do 4 check-ins that day
- 4 pipelines, each with a build and release stage are created (1 for each check-in). The build phases complete as the code is merged
- I don't want to deploy after every check-in so I schedule the release stage to run overnight

Once it reaches the release scheduled time isn't it going to kick off 4 simultaneous deployments for each pipeline that was created that day? How would I ensure it only schedules the latest? What if I wanted to ensure it also runs that deployment stage even if there have been no code changes?

I can solve this requirement with classic releases by scheduling the release to be created and deployed at a certain time with the latest artifact. It then doesn't matter how many builds were run that day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you schedule a stage to run at a particular time of day in a multi stage azure devops pipeline but for only the latest build?

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you could use the [cron parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers)(Scheduled triggers) to set the deployment. Then it could schedule a stage to run at a particular time of day.

> How would I ensure it only schedules the latest

To use the latest artifacts , you could add the [download build/pipeline artifacts task]
[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) in your deployment stage and set the version as latest.

At the same time, you could use [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) to determine the stage to run.

Here is my example:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
 
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: A
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.Sourcesdirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'drop'
          publishLocation: 'Container'


- stage: B
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        inputs:
          buildType: 'specific'
          project: 'Googletest'
          pipeline: '507'
          buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
          downloadType: 'single'
          artifactName: 'drop'
          downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

**Result:**

When you checkin changes and trigger the build , it will run the first stage(build).

When the pipeline is triggered by Schedule , it will run the second stage(deployment).

[image]

The deployment stage will download the latest artifacts.It then doesn't matter how many builds were run that day.

Comment: Thanks for this. It did help although I've now run into the issue of not being able to manually deploy a stage after the pipeline has been created. I believe it's explained here - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/specify-manual-stages-in-multi-stage-yaml-pipeline/629260

Comment: Yes. You are right. This is a feature request. If the answer could give you some help, you may consider accepting it . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend breaking out your pipelines into two distinct processes:

1. **Build Verification**: Have this run with every check-in to verify the integrity of your code.
2. **Nightly Deployments**: Run a full build & deployment on a schedule every night.

This takes the complexity out of the scenario, while still offering you build verification at check-in.

Comment: Do you think those could be combined in the same yaml file?

Comment: Not really. The only method that might work is using **separate branches for your nightly releases vs your build verification. In this case, you could use the **condition:** attribute to restrict which branches you'd build verification is triggered from. You'd include both a branch trigger and a schedule in this case. This would allow build verification to only proceed, while your nightly builds are released from a separate branch. I'd not recommend this though, two separate pipelines would be the cleanest way to accomplish what you're looking for.